I'm looking to deploy a docker image from Google Artifact Registry on GKE using rest API
I am trying to deploy a Docker image stored in Google Artifact Registry to my Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster using the REST API
I have search in google cloud docs. But apparently Google Cloud offers an API only to manage the cluster/nodes configuration and not the deployment.
With some extra googling it seems I would need to interact directly with kubernetes API but here I'm stacked

The flow is: you  use the rest API (ie via gcloud) to get an auth token and then use the kubernetes API (ie via kubectl) to manage your kubernetes resources as you would do for any other k8s cluster. If you want to combine both in 1 flow, you could use terraform, as terraform happens to have a GCP module, and a regular k8s module that can be used to deploy to any cluster, including a GKE one: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstarts/create-cluster-using-terraform

I have got the auth token and the GKE api endpoint by running: kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.server}'. Now I'm trying to call https://${cluster_api_endpoint}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods with header 'Authorization': Bearer ${api_token}. However I'm getting UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE - unable to verify the first certificate

I would assume your token isn't correct, but I don't get why you are trying to directly calling to use the k8s API instead of using kubectl to deploy if you already use kubectl to get the token. Or use one of the hundreds of kubernetes client libraries that exist for pretty much every programming language.

Because I'm building a platform that lets you deploy workloads for a specific application. So when you create a job, we need to deploy that job with the specific cpus config you specified

RESOLVED: it turned out the auth token and endpoint were wrong.
I had to log into the cluster terminal from google cloud and create a service account kubectl create serviceaccount <name> and create an auth token for the service account to use to authorize requests to k8s.
Only after I was able to call
https://${cluster_api_endpoint}/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments

Which was returning 403 because I had to create a role for the service account and assign it with rolebinding. Once configured the correct role, I was able to deploy a container image
